# Why IIS HTTPS Redirect doesn't work with API?

Tags: python, iis

I am using the following rule to redirect a HTTPS request to HTTP. It works fine when I access my application via the browser. But accessing it via the Python API leads to an error "Your Api endpoint at xxx is not available or not responding."

Any ideas why the API behavior might be different to the browser?

```xml
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Browsers are smart enough to follow 30x redirection responses to use the new URLs, but your Python code might not. The solution is to improve your Python code to do the same or use a smart enough HTTP client module/library.

Comment: You can use FRT to get more information with your request, [Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).